# echo not working, at ($row=0)

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
 $soil_ph = $_POST['soilph'];
 $query = "select ph_id,ph_name,ph_from,ph_to from tbl_soilph 
 where '$soil_ph' between ph_from and ph_to";

 $result = mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
if ($row == 0)
{
echo 'Invalid or out of range';
}
else
{
$ph = $row['ph_name'];
echo $row['ph_name'];
}
}
?>
```

---echo not working @ ($row=0)--- can  someone help me?
the code above works fine it gives result, but when there's no data it doesn't show the message "invalid input"?

Comment: The `while` condition already checks the `$row` variable for truthiness. Which is why the inner `if` will never see the absent value. Check with _num_rows (or whatever the dated mysql function is).

Comment: can you give me the right code? mario?

Comment: you have to do in different if statement , check my answer

Comment: Do not you getting your answer yet???

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should always escape your variables before using them in database queries (unless you use prepared statements, which you should):

```
$soil_ph = $_POST['soilph'];
$query = "SELECT ph_id, ph_name, ph_from, ph_to 
    FROM tbl_soilph 
    WHERE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($soil_ph) . "' BETWEEN ph_from AND ph_to";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

To inspect whether you have any results, you should use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) after making sure the query didn't fail:

```
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // do your stuff
    }
} else {
    // aww, nothing there
}
```

Further reading: [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$soil_ph = $_POST['soilph'];
$query = "select ph_id,ph_name,ph_from,ph_to from tbl_soilph 
where '$soil_ph' between ph_from and ph_to";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)) {

 while() {

 }
} else {
  echo 'invalid input';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code , you have change the way you loop

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {

    echo 'Invalid or out of range';

}else{

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

         $ph = $row['ph_name'];
         echo $row['ph_name'];
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually mysql_fetch_array function return a single dimension array at each time execute. You can do like this:

```
if($results){
echo 'No Results';
}else{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
if(!empty($row)){ 
echo $row['ph_name'];
}else{
echo 'invalid';
}
}
```

Comment: @raine: Maybe ph_name is blank?